# Recently installed applications missing from $PATH

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, path

When I install apps using `apt-get` or `NVM` or `NPM` on Ubuntu, I can type the command and it works.

Then I log out of the shell and log back in. Now none of the things I installed work when I ask for them because they are apparently not on my `$PATH`.

How can I ensure that whatever apps I install are always added to my `$PATH` automatically?

Answer (score 6):

Apps installed via the package manager should install to locations such as `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc. which should be in your `$PATH` by default.

I think the error must be somewhere else. Are you typing the name of the command correctly?

Try running locating the binary (locate, find, or its 'installed files' as shown in your package manager) and check your `$PATH` (`echo $PATH`) to see if everything matches.

Answer (score 0):

Many shells maintain a cache of programs in the search path, so as to speed up invocations. Depending on the shell and its configuration, it might maintain a cache of negative results, in which case it won't notice that a program now exists.

Run `hash -r` (or `rehash` if you're using tcsh) to clear your shell's cache. It should pick up newly installed programs.